# What is the purpose of the Motor Run Capacitor?

Tags: capacitor, motor

Looking at a control box for a marine Air Conditioner and it has a HUGE capacitor in it.  The schematics label it a "Motor Run Capacitor", but I always thought it was just used to start the motor.

What function does a huge cap like this have in running the motor?

The Air Conditioner is being run off AC power from a generator, no DC involved.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's more than likely a single phase induction motor.

Unlike a 3 phase motor that can automatically generate a rotating magnetic field, a single phase induction motor has to manufacture one by using 4 stator poles. Two of them are fed with the regular AC voltage and the other two are fed AC via a capacitor. If the value of the capacitor and winding inductance is chosen to electrically be a low Q resonant circuit at the AC frequency supplied, the voltage phase difference between the two sets of stator coils will be approximately 90 degrees and this will set the motor spinning. [Here](http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/vol_2/chpt_13/9.html#02486.png) is a decent link and below is a snapshot: -

[image]